# User input for a Roulette Wheel

Tags: c, animation, user-input

For coursework I have to create a Roulette Wheel (European) which:

- Read from standard input one valid bet on a single number
- Select a winning number at random
- Is an animation of 2 or more frames
- Display the user bet and winning number

So far I've animated the wheel using a for loop and there is a ball that lands on a random number.

I have attempted to write some code for the user input

```
int bet[3];  
int result;
scanf( "%d" , &bet);
if (bet >=0 && bet <= 36); result = 1;
printf("Your bet is number %d", &bet);
```

When inputting a bet into the stdin console the program does not display the contents of the printf functions and just goes straight to the animation. Any suggestions or help to improve the user input would be appreciated

Comment: Why is `bet` an array?

Comment: My thinking was that the user inputs their bet into an array and named it as such

Comment: Then use `bet[i]` instead of `bet` (and `&bet[i]` instead of `&bet`) and set `i` for each bet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to terminate the output with a newline to flush the output buffer

```
printf("Your bet is number %d\n", &bet);
//                           ^^ newline to flush output buffer
```

Also, you really don't need an array of 3 ints for input. A single `int` is enough

```
int bet;
scanf("%d", &bet);
// ...
printf("Your bet is number %d\n", bet);
```

If you want to keep the arrays of 3 ints, you need to change your code

```
int bet[3];  
int result;
scanf( "%d" , &bet[1]); // or &bet[0] or bet + 2
if (bet[1] >=0 && bet[1] <= 36); result = 1;
printf("Your bet is number %d", bet[1]);
```

Also (I noticed while editing the code above) you have an extra semicolon in your `if` line

```
if (bet >=0 && bet <= 36); result = 1;
//                       ^ ???
```

The `result = 1;` is not part of the `if`.

Comment: Thank you, thats really helpful. Yes the extra semicolon was a mistake

Answer (score 0):

```
if (bet >=0 && bet <= 36); result = 1;
```

This does *not* do what you want.  The semicolon after your `if` statement is most likely a mistake. right now, `result` will *always* be set to 1.

Instead:

```
if (bet >=0 && bet <= 36) {
    result = 1;
}
```